# checking for equality before assigning an object to another

Tags: c#

if i where to assign an object to another object, and there is 50% chance that they are equal, is checking for the equality useful?

i know that it could be useful in a property setter, for example to avoid firing the property changed event, but what about in the following cases, does it make any difference?

```
private SomeObject currentObject;
//assign only if objects are not equal
public void GetResults(SomeObject obj)
{
    if(currentObject!= obj)
    currentObject = obj;

    //....
}


//assign no matter what
public void GetResults(SomeObject obj)
{
    currentObject = obj;
    //....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on how you define equality of your objects:

If you have some custom equality comparison, where e.g. two objects are equal if some (all?) members match, then it depends on your app's logic if you want to have a common reference to that object, which might save some memory for example.

Otherwise, if you're just interested if it's the same object, there's no point - the cost of assigning the reference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

It's only useful is you are going to trigger some event, like when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Otherwise, it's not necessary IMHO.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you're considering "Micro optimizations" then direct assignment will perform better.

So I'd stick with this

```
currentObject = obj;
```

Checking for equality is adding another overhead for comparing it. It just adds some more IL code to be executed.

Some time back I've done some benchmarking to see which is better, results shown that direct assignment is better. Right now I don't have the code interested people can try measuring and figure out.